# Why time is changing when add event

Tags: xcode

self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

```
NSLog(@"check addevent time :%@",self.date);
```

if ([_eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])

```
{
    [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted){
            addEventgranted = 1;
            EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:_eventStore];
            [event setTitle:self.showNameTitle];
            [event setStartDate: self.date];
            [event setEndDate:[[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeInterval:self.duration sinceDate:event.startDate]];
            NSTimeInterval alarmOffset = -300;
            EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:alarmOffset];
            [event addAlarm:alarm];

            [event setCalendar:[_eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
            NSError *err;
            [_eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

            NSLog(@"Check error %@",err);
            self.str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"check self.str :: %@",self.str);
```

I log this out before adding event

:: check addevent time :2015-04-07 13:55:00 +0000

but when adding the time change to

8:55 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this log shows you GMT time formate. 
Don`t worry this is proper data which is you saved.
Just use date formatter to log you data . 
You will get proper date log. 
Use below syntax to log your date.

```
NSDate* dateTime = [NSDate date];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS.SSS'Z'"];
NSString* stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTime];

NLog(@"%@",stringDate);
```